# Archive upload failed with error: ITMS-90470 Missing TVTopShelfImage.TVTopShelfPrimaryImageWide key

Tags: xcode, tvos

Do you know why this is happening and most important how to fix it?
Adding the key with what value?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Starting in tvOS 10 you must include a wide top shelf image, `Top Shelf Image Wide`, with a size of `2320px by 720px @1x`. [tvOS Human Interface Guidelines: Icons and Images](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/).

If `Top Shelf Image Wide` is not already in your `Assets.xcassets` you can create one manually, or with the `+` `Add a Group or Image Set` button. For example:

[image]

The crop area is still `1920px x 720px @1x` when the top shelf image is displayed on the Apple TV. So, if you're using any text or images that you don't want cut off make sure to make them centered in those dimensions. For example:

[image]

The areas in red are only used for sliding in your top shelf image when your app icon becomes highlighted on the Apple TV home screen.

---

EDIT:

Check your target's Build Settings.

[image]

Comment: Thx for the thoughtful answer. I do have the image in the Assets.casset and of the size you reported (I should have added it in the question) however, I still getting that cryptic error. Any other idea on what it could be?

Comment: @amok I've edited my answer. I found a reference in the targets build settings. Besides that, try uploading your build using Application Loader instead of XCode:  XCode> Open Developer Tool> Application Loader.