# How to fix Error ITMS-90513 caused by missing TVTopShelfImage.TVTopShelfPrimaryImageWide in your app's Info.plist

Tags: xcode, tvos

Detailed error description:

> ERROR ITMS-90513: "Missing Info.plist Key. Your app's Info.plist in
>   'Payload/xxx.app' must contain the
>   'TVTopShelfImage.TVTopShelfPrimaryImageWide' key."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Archive upload failed with error: ITMS-90470 Missing TVTopShelfImage.TVTopShelfPrimaryImageWide key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810934/archive-upload-failed-with-error-itms-90470-missing-tvtopshelfimage-tvtopshelfp)

Answer (score 9):

Starting with tvOS 10 you also have to provide wide version of TopShelfImage.

Find it in asset catalog right next to your icon and the old TopShelfImage.

Project settings / General / App Icons and Launch images / App Icons source / click the little right arrow on the right.

Comment: And the size of the Wide Top Shelf Image should be 2320 x 720

Comment: I have an image with the side 2320 x 720 in the top shelf wide yet it's showing me the same error