# CFBundlePrimaryIcon key flagged as missing when its not in TVOS app

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, plist, tvos

Long time iOS dev making my first TVOS app, and I get the "missing info plist CFBundlePrimaryIcon" error, although it appears that the value is actually present in the plist. The file is a 400x240 png, and is in the package. Here's a screenshot showing the plist and the error.

I'm also using an asset catalog with the icon in there as well. I manually added all the plist icon entries attempting to work around this. Here is the icon in the asset file:

[image]

I don't understand how to clear this error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So, this is technically not an answer to how to fix the project errors shown above, but rather a heavy-handed workaround.

Part of my problems originally had to do with the icon layers, and as it says in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810934/archive-upload-failed-with-error-itms-90470-missing-tvtopshelfimage-tvtopshelfp), setting the back layers to no alpha channel, and leaving the front layers transparent corrected that.

So I just made a whole new project, copied all the files over, including the icon and other image files, and voila it uploaded the first time with no errors and is now waiting for beta test review.

My best guess is that while I was messing around with the asset catalog I deleted some "magic setting" of some kind that is too obscure to recreate manually.

Hope this helps someone along the line.